How does k3s expose nodeports on linux?
I am investigating connectivity issues where k3s nodeport only accepts incommoding connections on one ip/interface but not on others. During this I realized that ports exposed using  k3s nodeport do not show up in
netstat -lpn nor in ip -all netns exec netstat -lpn
I cannot either find any iptables rule that would "redirect" traffic to one of the ports I see when doing netstat -lpn (searching with iptables-save | grep )
What linux feature does k3s use to redirect incoming traffic to other ports and into the specific container network namespace?
